# Make a PDF file available to Community users

Tags: community

How can I make a pdf file available to Community users?  Based on my searching, it sounds like I need to upload to Community via a Community license?  I am not clear on exactly what I need to do

Comment: Please refrain from multiple punctuation (`???`, `!!!`, `...`, etc).

Comment: Content and Chatter Files can be used to expose files to a community depending on the license type you have available as per [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0). 

Uploading the file as document should help but you cannot expose the documents tab directly, so this will need a custom solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me to be able to add a file to a custom object & Customer Community users can view it.

Triggr:

```
trigger ShareFiles2 on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) { for(ContentDocumentLink l:Trigger.new)l.Visibility='AllUsers'; }
```

Test for Trigger:

```
@isTest(seealldata=false)

private class TestSharedFiles2 {
static testMethod void TestSharedFiles2() {

        //Create test tier level
    Fee_and_Discount__c tier = new Fee_and_Discount__c(Begin_Date1__c=Date.valueOf('2008-01-01'), Type__c='Fee', 
                                                       In_kind1__c=5.00, Cash1__c=5.00, Name='Tier 1');
insert tier;


    //Create test account
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Your Account Name', 
                              recruitment_begin_date__c= Date.valueOf('2008-01-01'),
                             AccountSource='Website',
                              tier_level__c=tier.id,
                             recruitment_primary_contact__c='0056A000000zP7Z',
                             billingstate='North Carolina',
                              GC_Lottery_Winner__c=Date.valueOf('2018-01-01'),
                              TAC_Lottery_Winner__c=Date.valueOf('2018-01-01'),
                             priority__c='High');

    insert acct;


ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
  Title = 'Penguins',
  PathOnClient = 'Penguins.jpg',
  VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
  IsMajorVersion = true
);
        system.Test.startTest();

insert contentVersion;    
List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

//create ContentDocumentLink  record 
ContentDocumentLink cdl = New ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.LinkedEntityId = acct.id;
cdl.ContentDocumentId = documents[0].Id;
cdl.shareType = 'V';
insert cdl;
        System.Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify that the all option is only for intermal and Community users.  I cannot have the information available to the public.  If the trigger is the answer I am going to work on that.  I have not written one but now is the time to learn.  Do you have a recommended webpage to learn this from?

Comment: Please use comments to add comments not answers. To learn how to create a trigger start with the trailhead module https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers though I would advise doing this one first https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_database

Comment: I added a trigger to production that I thought should work to make new documents added to my Salesforce instance viewable by Customer Community users.  This isn't happening.  Can you provide guidance?

trigger ShareFiles2 on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) { for(ContentDocumentLink l:Trigger.new)l.Visibility='AllUsers'; }

Comment: I am happy to report I got this to work.  I can add files to a custom object & they are viewable by my Customer Community users.  Thank you for the help.